# Mathplotlib pandas-Plotting average line to scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I have a scatter plot created from two columns of a pandas data frame and I would like to add a line across each axis representing the average. Is this possible with a scatter plot?

```
plt.title("NFL Conversion Rates", fontsize=40)

# simulating a pandas df['team'] column
types = df.Tm
x_coords = df['3D%']
y_coords = df['4D%']
binsy = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85]
binsx = [30,35,40,45,50,55]

avg_y = y_coords.mean()
avg_y = round(avg_y, 1)
display(avg_y)

avg_x = x_coords.mean()
avg_x = round(avg_x, 1)
display(avg_x)


for i,type in enumerate(types):
    x = x_coords[i]
    y = y_coords[i]
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=30, marker='o', edgecolor='black', cmap='purple', linewidth=1, alpha = 0.5)
    plt.text(x+0.2, y+0.1, type, fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel('3rd Down Conversion Percentage',fontsize=30)
    plt.ylabel('4th Down Conversion Percentage', fontsize=30)
    plt.xticks(binsx)
    plt.yticks(binsy)
```

[image]

Comment: You can try  `plt.axvline(<value>,color='red',ls='--')` and `plt.axhline(<value>,color='red',ls='--')`. Substitute <value> with the value at which you want the lines

Comment: I now added that as an answer. Consider up-voting & accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try
`plt.axvline(<value>,color='red',ls='--')` and `plt.axhline(<value>,color='red',ls='--')`. Substitute  with the value at which you want the lines